# React Redux Assign Arrow Function Warning in reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this Warning in my React App?

> src/reducers/posts.js
> Line 3:1:  Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default

```
import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE } from '../constants/actionTypes';

export default (posts = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL:
            return action.payload;
        case UPDATE:
            return posts.map((post) => post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post);
        case CREATE:
            return [ ...posts, action.payload];
        case DELETE:
            return posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return posts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty self explanatory. Assign the arrow function to variable, then export that variable as the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add variable to your function:

```
export default const variable = (posts = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL:
            return action.payload;
        case UPDATE:
            return posts.map((post) => post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post);
        case CREATE:
            return [ ...posts, action.payload];
        case DELETE:
            return posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return posts;
    }
}
```

JavaScript have to know what are you exporting

Comment: or can use `modul.exports = {variable}`

Comment: That worked for me! I assigned a variable and then called somewhere else with destructuring. Thanks Roman.

Comment: I get `TS1109: Expression expected.`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot **export default** and **declare a variable** at the same time.
Try this instead:

```
const variable = (posts = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL:
            return action.payload;
        case UPDATE:
            return posts.map((post) => post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post);
        case CREATE:
            return [ ...posts, action.payload];
        case DELETE:
            return posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return posts;
    }
}

export default variable
```

Or export default with the **traditional named function**:

```
export default function variable(posts = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL:
            return action.payload;
        case UPDATE:
            return posts.map((post) => post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post);
        case CREATE:
            return [ ...posts, action.payload];
        case DELETE:
            return posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return posts;
    }
}
```